# Understanding Distribute when applied with a user defined function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I would expect this

```
F[x_] := Module[{aux = x},    aux = X]; 
{a + b + c, e+ f} // Map[Distribute@*F]
```

to yield

> {3X, 2X}

instead, the function is not distributed over plus, yielding

> {X, X}

Clearing F, `Clear[F]`, I get what I expected

> {F[a]+F[b]+F[c],F[d]+F[e]}

How to distribute the function before evaluating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[F];
F[x_] := X;
{a + b + c, e + f} // Map[Distribute@*Hold[F]] // ReleaseHold
(* {3 X, 2 X} *)

Clear[F];
F[x : Except[_Plus]] := X;
{a + b + c, e + f} // Map[Distribute@*F]
(* {3 X, 2 X} *)

Clear[F];
F[x_ /; Head[x] =!= Plus] := X;
{a + b + c, e + f} // Map[Distribute@*F]
(* {3 X, 2 X} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the three (!) alternatives. Do you know why if `F[x_]:=x^2` the Hold is not needed?

Comment: Do you mean `F[x_] := x^2` or `F[x_] := X^2`?

Comment: Small case. When it actually uses the argument `F[x_]:=x^2`

Comment: Because in that case, it is not `F` that is getting distributed itself, but `Power` (`^2`). Compare the [following evaluation traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6ipb.png).

Comment: Great thank you. I didn't know about `Trace`. So useful!